# JavaScript Autocomplete Plugin - How do you exclude parameters in an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, autocomplete, javascript-objects

I'm using a plugin called Autocomplete by [devbridge.com](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/). What I'm having a problem with is filtering the autocomplete results to exclude certain options depending on what the user typed in the other text box. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="check_in_questions">
    <label id="label_new_home" for="location_pickup">Pickup Up Location</label>
    <br>
    <input id="location_pickup" class="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Pickup Location">
</div>
<div class="check_in_questions">
    <label id="label_new_home" for="location_dropoff">Drop-Off Location</label>
    <br>
    <input id="location_dropoff" class="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Drop-Off Location">
</div>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
var data = [
{ 
    value: 'Orlando International Airport (MCO)', 
    data: { 
            category: 'Airport',
            address: '1 Jeff Fuqua Blvd., Orlando, FL',
            airport: 'MCO',
            location: 'Orlando'
          } 
},
{ 
    value: 'Orlando Sanford International Airport (SFB)', 
    data: { 
            category: 'Airport',
            address: '1200 Red Cleveland Blvd., Sanford, FL',
            airport: 'SFB',
            location: 'Orlando'
          } 
},
{ 
    value: 'Port Canaveral Cruise Terminal', 
    data: { 
            category: 'Cruise Terminal',
            address: 'Port Canaveral, FL',
            airport: '',
            location: 'Port Canaveral'
          } 
},
{ 
    value: 'Baymont Inn & Suites Florida Mall/Orlando', 
    data: { 
            category: 'Hotel',
            address: '8820 S Orange Blossom Trail, Orlando, FL',
            airport: '',
            location: 'Orlando'
          } 
}
];
```

```
$('.autocomplete').devbridgeAutocomplete( {
    lookup: data,
    groupBy: 'category',
    lookupFilter: function (suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {
        return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0 
        || suggestion.data.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0 
        || suggestion.data.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0 
        || suggestion.data.address.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0 
        || suggestion.data.airport.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
    }
});

$('#location_pickup').change(function() {
    if (get_location($(this).val()) != '') {
        $(this).setOptions({ params: 
                            { data: 
                            { location: !get_location($('#location_dropoff').val()) }
                            } 
                          });
    }
});

$('#location_dropoff').change(function() {
    if (get_location($(this).val()) != '') {
        $(this).setOptions({ params: 
                            { data: 
                            { location: !get_location($('#location_pickup').val()) }
                            } 
                          });
    }
});

function get_location(string) {
    var location;

    if (data.some(function(item, index, array) { i = index; return item.value == string})) {
        location = data[i].data.location;
    }

    return location;
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to set the `params` property to exclude the same location from the other text box for both text boxes.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lftokxhd)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do your `change` events. This can all be done through the plugins `filter` function.

```js
var data = [
   { value: 'Orlando International Airport (MCO)', data: { category: 'Airport', address: '1 Jeff Fuqua Blvd., Orlando, FL', airport: 'MCO', location: 'Orlando'} },
 { value: 'Orlando Sanford International Airport (SFB)', data: { category: 'Airport', address: '1200 Red Cleveland Blvd., Sanford, FL', airport: 'SFB', location: 'Orlando'} },
 { value: 'Port Canaveral Cruise Terminal', data: { category: 'Cruise Terminal', address: 'Port Canaveral, FL', airport: '', location: 'Port Canaveral'} },
 { value: 'Baymont Inn & Suites Florida Mall/Orlando', data: { category: 'Hotel', address: '8820 S Orange Blossom Trail, Orlando, FL', airport: '', location: 'Orlando'} }
    ];

$('.autocomplete').each(function(i, item) { 
$(item).devbridgeAutocomplete( {
    lookup: data,
    groupBy: 'category',
    lookupFilter: function (suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {
        
        // First ensure not the same as other location
        var $check = $(item).attr("id") == "location_pickup" ? 
            $('#location_dropoff').val() : $('#location_pickup').val();
        
  // Check location conditions
        if (
  (suggestion.data.category == 'Port' && get_category($check) == 'Port') 
  || (suggestion.data.category == 'Hotel' && get_category($check) == 'Hotel') 
  || (suggestion.data.category == 'Airport' && get_category($check) == 'Airport')  
  || (suggestion.data.category == 'Airport' && get_category($check) == 'Hotel') && (suggestion.data.location == 'Orlando' && get_location($check) == 'Orlando')
  || (suggestion.data.category == 'Hotel' && get_category($check) == 'Airport') && (suggestion.data.location == 'Orlando' && get_location($check) == 'Orlando')
  || ((suggestion.data.category == 'Port' && get_category($check) == 'Hotel') && (suggestion.data.location == get_location($check))) 
  || ((suggestion.data.category == 'Hotel' && get_category($check) == 'Port') && (suggestion.data.location == get_location($check)))
  ) return false;
        
        return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0 
        || suggestion.data.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0 
        || suggestion.data.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0 
        || suggestion.data.address.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0 
        || suggestion.data.airport.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
    }
});
});

function get_location(string) {
    var location;

    if (data.some(function(item, index, array) { i = index; return item.value == string})) {
        location = data[i].data.location;
    }

    return location;
}

function get_category(string) {
    var category;

    if (data.some(function(item, index, array) { i = index; return item.value == string})) {
        category = data[i].data.category;
    }

    return category;
}
```

```css
.check_in_questions {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
input {
    width: 250px;
}

.autocomplete-suggestions { border: 1px solid #999; background: #FFF; overflow: auto; }
.autocomplete-suggestion { padding: 5px 10px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
.autocomplete-selected { background: #F0F0F0; }
.autocomplete-suggestions strong { font-weight: normal; color: #3399FF; }
.autocomplete-group { padding: 10px; }
.autocomplete-group strong { display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; font-size: 15px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dev.goportorlando.com/plugins/autocomplete/js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>

<div class="check_in_questions">
    <label id="label_new_home" for="location_pickup">Pickup Up Location</label>
    <br>
    <input id="location_pickup" class="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Pickup Location">
</div>
<div class="check_in_questions">
    <label id="label_new_home" for="location_dropoff">Drop-Off Location</label>
    <br>
    <input id="location_dropoff" class="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Drop-Off Location">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is only checking if the two values of the text boxes are the same. I need for it to check if the `location` attribute of the `data` object are the same in the two text boxes.

Comment: Then simply modify the comparison to also use your `get_location` function.

Comment: But I need it to show other locations and not disable the drop down.

Comment: Ok, I redid some of your code and it seems to work now. I will mark this as the answer.